# hibernate one to many adding child object automatically exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Below are my two entity classes with one to many and many to one relationship.

```
Parent AuditMst:

public class AuditMst implements Serializable {


    /*@Id
    @Column(name="AUDIT_ID")
    private String auditId;*/

    @Id
    @Column(name="AUDIT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long auditId;

    private String action;

    @Column(name="DATE_TIME")
    private Timestamp dateTime;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AuditDetail
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auditMst", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<AuditDetail> auditDetails;

Child entity: Audit Details

public class AuditDetail implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="FIELD_NAME")
    private String fieldName;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AuditMst
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "AUDIT_ID", referencedColumnName = "AUDIT_ID")})
    private AuditMst auditMst;
```

When i try to add the save audit mst and audit details list hibernate gives me exception:

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'AUDIT_ID' cannot be null

This is a one to many relationship. And i am using spring data jpa and hibernate.

In my audit Listner:

```
AuditMst auditMst = new AuditMst();
  auditMst.setAction("add");
for(Object propNameObject : map.keySet()){
AuditDetail auditDetail = new AuditDetail();
String propertyName = (String) propNameObject;
Object property1 = propUtils.getProperty(oldObject, propertyName);
Object property2 = propUtils.getProperty(newObject, propertyName);
 auditDetail.setFieldName(propertyName);
auditDetail.setOldValue(property1.toString());
auditDetail.setNewValue(property2.toString);      
auditDetailList.add(auditDetail);
}
 auditMst.setAuditDetails(auditDetailList);
auditMstService.addAuditMst(auditMst);


ServiceImpl:

@Transactional
    public AuditMst addAuditMst(AuditMst auditMst){
        AuditMst savedAuditMst = auditMstRepository.save(auditMst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a many to one relationship, then in you AuditDetail change your ManyToOne to:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "AUDIT_ID")
private AuditMst auditMst;
```

But be sure you have the column AUDIT_ID created in the table related with the entity AuditDetail. And as the relationship is in cascade, save the object AuditMst only

And in your java code:

```
AuditMst auditMst = new AuditMst();
auditMst.setAction("add");
for(Object propNameObject : map.keySet()){
    AuditDetail auditDetail = new AuditDetail();
    String propertyName = (String) propNameObject;
    Object property1 = propUtils.getProperty(oldObject, propertyName);
    Object property2 = propUtils.getProperty(newObject, propertyName);
    auditDetail.setFieldName(propertyName);
    auditDetail.setOldValue(property1.toString());
    auditDetail.setNewValue(property2.toString);      
    //Here you need to add the original object to make work the on cascade.
    auditDetail.setAuditMst(auditMst);
    auditDetailList.add(auditDetail);
}
```

Comment: @jack do you have the FK from the destiny table, audit_detail? the code you used was the same? can you add the full stack trace of your exception?

Comment: could you add the piece of code where you create those entities and save them?

Comment: what i want to see is how do you create the object AuditMst and how do you add the details to the list. please update your question with that piece of code i think the problem could be in there

Comment: I have added the piece of code you are looking for.

Comment: could you add the block of code where you create the AuditMst entity and add the AuditDetail in your original question?

Comment: @jack your problem was that in the object auditDetail, you only add to the list of the parent object, but the relational column is in the secondary table, so you have to use the method setAuditMst() to let know the column which value will be the join with AuditMst

Comment: Thank you so much cralfaro. Yes it is working fine now. I am able to persist both the mst and the audit detail.

Comment: Ya i forgot to validate it.

Comment: @jack ups did validate yet? maybe should i add more details to help better the next person have the same problem or is ok?

Comment: Yes i have validated. Yes you can add more details.